# SQL create copies of rows into same table

Tags: php, sql

Say my SQL table looks like this:

```
Week | User  | Score
-----+-------+------
1    | Bob   |  14
1    | Tim   |  22
2    | Bob   | -19
2    | Time  | -12
2    | Steve |  31
```

I want to create an SQL query to duplicate every entry from the most recent week (in this case 2), and paste them into the same same where week increases by one, and the "score" column is zero'd out. The result below:

```
Week | User  | Score
-----+-------+------
1    | Bob   |  14
1    | Tim   |  22
2    | Bob   | -19
2    | Time  | -12
2    | Steve |  31
3    | Bob   |
3    | Tim   |
3    | Steve |
```

Comment: You should use procedures, refer to: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is just take the latest values and insert them back in with slight modifications:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (id, name, val)
SELECT id+1, name, null
FROM my_table
WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM my_table)
```

See this [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/86a51/2) for a working example.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, the code you have given will have duplicate primary keys.
`INSERT INTO my_table (week, name, val)` then just autoincrement the primary keys.

Comment: The id column can be identity if you want it to be. The original question had weeks though, not just arbitrary ids.